# Firefox rearranges the order of form input attributes

Tags: html, ajax, firefox

Does anybody know anything about this, and how to prevent it.

I populate a div through AJAX with a form from a php file. 
The input element is written as the following in php

```
echo ('<input type="text" name="court_type_name" id="court_type_name_input-' . $itemID . '" class="dataField" data-rule-length="4,6" data-rule-required="true" />');
```

I do form validation based on the order of the attributes. Later attributes have higher priority.For example this case 'Required' has priority over Lenght-In-Between

In Chrome Inspect, I see following. Which is the way I have written originally, and the code works as intended.

```
<input type="text" name="court_type_name" id="court_type_name_input-9" class="dataField" data-rule-length="4,6" data-rule-required="true">
```

However in Firefox inspect I see the following. Please note that the order of the attributes has changed. This results in 'data-rule-length' taking priority over 'data-rule-required'.

ScreenShot of FF Inspect:

[image]

In addition to this. there are more inconsistencies.

If i copy/paste right off the Inspect window, I get a totally different attribute order. Different than my original, and different than what it is visually available in FF Inspect. The code however works consistent with the visual representation.

```
<input name="court_type_name" id="court_type_name_input-9" class="dataField" data-rule-length="4,6" data-rule-required="true" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are, by definition, unordered. You can't depend on the order they appear in. You must encode that information some other way. e.g. another data attribute.

```
data-rules="length required" data-rule-length="4,6" data-rule-required="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be turned off as far as I know. This is the way FF displays it.
If you right click and select `Edit as HTML` it should show the original order.
The order of the attributes shouldn't affect the result, but again, its only the display that is in a reordered manner.